# Java Synchronized is neccessary in this?

Tags: java, synchronization

```
public void giveTrust(final CoupleTrust action, final Object... objects)
{
    final L2PcInstance player = (L2PcInstance) objects[0];

    if (player == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    switch(action)
    {
         //Some code here about each case. Ex.

        case PVP:
        if (objects[1] !=null && objects[1] != player)
        {
            //Some code
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

My method is called every time a player kills a someone or kill a monster e.t.c
so basically if we speak of 500-900 players this method can AVRG been called about 1500 + times every minute or so. 
The code that is been executed is not big or heavy mostly some checks (null, get array value, calculate distance e.t.c) but the question is there any problem with synchronization? I mean different classes have access to this method (more than 20). Will this cause problems to synchronization especially when it get executed so many times? I call it via `SingletonHolder`:

```
public static final CoupleManager getInstance()
{
    return SingletonHolder._instance;
}
private static class SingletonHolder
{
    protected static final CoupleManager_instance= new CoupleManager();
}
```

So can anyone tell me? Do i have to use synchronize?

Comment: Synchronization has to with threading, not with how many other objects use this particular one. Your threading model though, is not obvious in your question, which makes it impossible to draw any conclusions to answer it.